# acess variable url in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

guys i am trying to make variable url to pass it to ajax call ..i know it is dummy but i cant find a solution and it doesnt work .. here is my code

```js
function GridLibrary(fileName) {
 this.fileName = fileName;

}


GridLibrary.prototype = {
  set_fileName: function(fileName){
   this.fileName = fileName;
  },
  get_fileName: function(){
   return this.fileName;
  }
};

GridLibrary.prototype.display = function() {
 $.ajax({

  url : get_fileName(),
  error : function(that, e) {

   console.log(e);
  },
  success : function(data) {
   var table = "<table>";
   $.each(data, function(index, MyList) {
    table += '<tr><td>' + MyList.id + '</td><td>' + MyList.name
      + '</td><td>' + MyList.age + '</td><td>'
      + MyList.feedback + '</td><tr>';
   });
   table += '</table>';
   $('body').append(table);

  }
 });
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by 'it doesn't work'? What does your console say? What does `get_fileName()` return?

Comment: it gives me get_fileName() is not function ... get_fileName() returns this.fileName

Comment: all i want to do is passing the url from outside source

Comment: Try changing `url : get_fileName()` to `url : this.get_fileName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a URL from an external source that is not your problem.

Use the 'this' keyword to fix your problem;

```
url : this.get_fileName()
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_fileName()` is not a function because it's a property on `GridLibrary.prototype`

you have to use `this.get_fileName()`